# Retrieve the last identity value of a column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I need to retrieve the last identity value of a column, I know that for example you can obtain it with this query:

```
USE MYDB
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT(('MYTABLE'),NORESEED)
GO
```

But I need it to be with C#, Linq, Entity Framework so that I can obtain that last identity value into a `int` number.

Comment: why? wanting to know the last value is a race condition waiting to happen; what are you *actually* trying to do here? Tip: the only thing you *should* need here is : `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (in the code that has just done an `INSERT`)

Comment: if you want to know the max... query `MAX(TheIdentiityColumn)` ...

Comment: I agree 10000% with @MarcGravell. But if you are deadset on doing this in a less than ideal solution you should look into [IDENT_CURRENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It will return the last inserted identity value even if that row has been deleted.

Comment: @SeanLange I will concede that `IDENT_CURRENT` is cleaner than `DBCC CHECKIDENT`; but that just changes the *scale* of terror showing on my face... slightly :)

Comment: @MarcGravell same here...everything about this post suggests it is dangerous at best.

Comment: in my particular case is because i know i will add a lot of records a the same time and just after that i need to add records with foreign key to another table, but they are added one after another, i know the "correct" way would be to store all those records i have just added and then add the other ones, but, but in my particular case is just for terms of making it faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(db.ExecuteStoreQuery<decimal>("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('DB.Table')", new object[0]).FirstOrDefault());
            return id;
```

This worked in my particular case

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
decimal[] results = _db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('MYTABLE')").ToArray();
 int maxValue = Convert.ToInt32(results[0]);
```

Comment: Problem is when someone delete the last record, identity wont be the same as last record, and I need to know last Identity value

Comment: @Beastbeast what does that mean? The next identity value doesn't change when you delete a row in the table. Maybe you are referring to a case where the most recent inserted row with an identity was deleted and DBCC throws an error?

Comment: indeed, sorry by last I mean the most recent record of a table, and yes, that particular case is why i need to retrieve identity and not id of last record

Comment: @Beastbeast, I have updated my above answer. So please verify and confirm